# Iterate through a table in Lua, in a function called from C

Tags: c, lua

I'm trying to call a Lua function from C.  The Lua function creates a table and then iterates through it.  It works as expected when called from Lua, but not when I call it from a C program.  Is there any reason why I can't do what I'm trying here?

test.lua:

```
function f()
    t = {["a"] = "aaa", ["b"] = "bbb", ["c"] = "ccc"}
    for z, v in t do
        print(t .. " " .. v)
    end
end
```

test.c:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char read_buffer[1024];

    lua_State *L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading test.lua");

    lua_getglobal(L, "f");

    if(lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));

    strncpy(read_buffer, lua_tostring(L, -1), sizeof(read_buffer));
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    printf("got from lua: %s\n", read_buffer);

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need to call `load_dofile()` instead of `lua_loadfile()`?

Comment: I believe luaL_dofile just calls lua_loadfile and lua_pcall: http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/luaL_dofile

Comment: You usual do this using [`lua_next`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_next). They even has an example there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm noticing a couple of issues above that's causing problems.

Over here:

```
function f()
  t = {["a"] = "aaa", ["b"] = "bbb", ["c"] = "ccc"}
  for z, v in t do
    print(t .. " " .. v)
  end
end
```

You can't use a lua table in the `for in` loop like that unless you make `t` callable in someway (eg. using `__call` for instance). More likely you're probably just trying to iterate through it, in which case you would use `pairs`:

```
  for z, v in pairs(t) do
  -- etc.
```

The other error is that you're trying to concat strings onto the table. Not sure what you were intending here. Perhaps you wanted to print the table address? You can use `tostring` for that.

The second issue I notice is in your `C` code:

```
if(lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) != 0)
```

So you're not expecting `f` to return anything unless there's an error. But right after that you try to convert the top item into a string:

```
strncpy(read_buffer, lua_tostring(L, -1), sizeof(read_buffer));
lua_pop(L, 1);
printf("got from lua: %s\n", read_buffer);
```

which doesn't make a whole lot of sense -- there may not be anything on the stack at this point. This is clearly a logic error in your code. If this is suppose to be a part of the error handling you should enclose it in braces so it's properly scoped:

```
if(lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    strncpy(read_buffer, lua_tostring(L, -1), sizeof(read_buffer));
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    printf("got from lua: %s\n", read_buffer);
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry - I meant to concat z and v, not t and v.  With the C code, my original Lua function that I simplified for testing did return a string - I guess I forgot to edit the C accordingly.  Didn't matter anyway since the Lua code would give me an error before that stuff.

Anyway, using `pairs` to iterate through worked, thanks very much.